# How to get ISBN number from .mobi file with python

Tags: python, kindle, isbn, mobipocket

Is there any way of fetching the ISBN number from a `.mobi` book using python?

Maybe there is a way of reading the `.mobi` files directely with python and search for 10 ints which is the ISBN number? if I open the mobi file with notepad i can find the number, but when i try to read the file I get a encoding error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Basically, you just need to [parse the PalmDB](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PalmDB/1.8.0) file format. The ISBN is stored in the `EXTH` header field of type `104`.

The Python PalmDB module I have linked above was somewhat immature when I wrote my Kindle collections manager, so I ended up implementing the relevant parts myself, see [kiehinen source code](http://code.google.com/p/kiehinen/source/browse/palm.py) for details.

If it is OK for you to use [my code](http://code.google.com/p/kiehinen/downloads/detail?name=kiehinen-0.3.2.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) (It has non-contagious [MIT License](http://code.google.com/p/kiehinen/source/browse/LICENSE.txt), should not be a problem, right?) you can just do:

```
>>> from kiehinen.ebook import Book
>>> b = Book("hobbit.mobi")
>>> b.exth['isbn'][0]
'9780618260300'
```

If not, please see the code linked above.