# Extract info from mobi

Tags: python, kindle

I am creating simple app for ebooks handling. Extracting info from epub files is piece of cake, there are plenty of packages for getting info about author of book, title, cover, description etc. But how to extract this informations from mobi files? Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/kroo/mobi-python). Although it's a `alpha quality software`, maybe it could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

- http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61986
- https://github.com/kroo/mobi-python
- [How to get ISBN number from .mobi file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465158/how-to-get-isbn-number-from-mobi-file-with-python)

And while it's a but large task, I'm suggesting to check [Calibre's repo](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre) and search for [metadata](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/3941163327d2df8b93f837cfdc55c8ec70b9f7cc/src/calibre/ebooks/metadata/meta.py) reading.

Or if you don't mind installing and calling a binary package, [Calibre has](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-meta.html) the ebook-meta command which allows reading and setting metadata.